# How can I import leaflet into an angular project?

Tags: angular, import, leaflet

I'm trying to use the leatflet package in my Angular project but I can't get it to work.

I installed leatflet with `npm install leatflet --save` then I'm including the dependencies in the `angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
            "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
],
"scripts": [
            "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"
],
```

My `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const myMap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  }

  onAdressSubmit(form) {
    console.log(form.value.adress);
  }
}
```

and inside the `app.component.html` I have a section with an id of map.

All I see is this:
[image: leaflet]

Does someone know where the problem lies and how to fix it?

Help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install the following to have Leaflet for Angular:

```
npm install leaflet
npm install @asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet
```

And `typings`:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/leaflet
```

Add the following in your Angular CLI .json:

- For Angular 5 and below: angular-cli.json
- For Angular 6 and above: angular.json

```
    {
        ...
        "styles": [
            "styles.css",
            **"./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"**
        ],
        ...
    }
```

Import Leaflet Module in app.module.ts:

```
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';

imports: [
    LeafletModule.forRoot()
]
```

And create a map:

```
<div style="height: 300px;"
     leaflet 
     [leafletOptions]="options">
</div>
```

And configure your options:

```
options = {
    layers: [
        tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 18, attribution: '...' })
    ],
    zoom: 5,
    center: latLng(46.879966, -121.726909)
};
```

Ref: [@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet)

**Edit:**

If you do not want to use the above package, then fix your issue with:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const myMap = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(myMap);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! After adding this tileLayer, I get the map. Can you explain what it does and do you know what didn't work in my approach?

Comment: @fonzane You need tiles for the map to load, if you don't put the server link, it won't load. You can choose tiles here: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/